# Hinges - how they make to follow rigid body?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm still confused with Physic and Constraints.
I'd like to have two bodies - connected together by hinge (let say vertical beam on a platform
, connected to horizontal beam). I'd like to move the platform from one place to another, keeping vertical beam on top, and have hinges working).
I've tried hook modifier, a few constraints - but it does not work somehow. Either vertical beam follows the platform and hinge stop working, or hinge is working and beam does not follow the platform.
I animate platform (with keyframes) and move it from one place to another.

Frame 1:

[image]

Frame 2:
[image]

Comment: can you pls show us (either by a video link or a gif or a sketch) how the animation should look like? what parts should move and how?

Comment: I edited the question, adding frame1 and frame2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hinge "empty" must look like this (orientation is very important for hinge):

[image]

I animated the block that you can see, the hinge works.

Blend file:

[image]

Result:

[image]

You can quickly create a hinge by selecting the two objects, then "object" -> rigid body -> connect. Then correct the empties rotation and position (if necessary).

[image]

here an example where the platform itself is animated:

[image]

in that case you have to keyframe the "animated" checkbox and of course the location of the platform.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. However, I see that you are pushing this by another passive block. Can you have the platform at the bottom animated, or does the whole block (platform + two beams) have to follow physic only?

Comment: of course you can animate the platform it by its own.

Comment: i updated my answer. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thank you.

Comment: Cool, so it's all about having second empty with correct orientation. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome